# scrollview will not scroll when android:softinputmode="adjustpan" enabled

Tags: android, scrollview

The situation:
I have an activity which at the moment has 5 "screens" wrapped in a ViewFlipper; below the ViewFLipper I have a blue bar which acts as a navigation bar showing what screen you are on.

The Problem:
When the soft keyboard appears, that blue nav bar shows up above it. So, I added `android:softinputmode="adjustpan"` to keep the nav bar at the bottom and now I can not scroll the view and some of my inputs are being blocked... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ViewFlipper android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/CreateNewAccountViewFlipper" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/NextBackScrollView1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TextView 
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/CreateNewAccountWelcomeMessage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:id="@+id/createNewAccountMessage"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="20px" 
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView>

        <com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/NextBackScrollView2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TextView 
                    android:padding="10dp" 
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/CreateNewAccountEmailMessage"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/createNewAccountEmailMessage"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </TextView>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Email Address" 
                    android:id="@+id/newEmail"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </EditText>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:hint="Confirm Email Address" 
                    android:id="@+id/newEmailConfirm"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView>

        <com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/NextBackScrollView3"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TextView android:padding="10dp" android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/CreateNewAccountPersonalInfoMessage"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/createNewAccountPersonalInfoMessage"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </TextView>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" 
                    android:hint="First Name"
                    android:id="@+id/newAccountFirstName" 
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </EditText>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" 
                    android:hint="Last Name"
                    android:id="@+id/newAccountLastName" 
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </EditText>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:hint="Street Address" 
                    android:id="@+id/newAccountStreetAddress"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </EditText>

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_weight="3" 
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:hint="City" 
                        android:id="@+id/newAccountCity"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress">
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_weight="1" 
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:hint="St" 
                        android:id="@+id/newAccountState"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress">
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_weight="2" 
                        android:maxLength="5"
                        android:hint="Zip" 
                        android:id="@+id/newAccountZipCode"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress">
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView>

        <com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/NextBackScrollView4"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TextView 
                    android:padding="10dp" 
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/CreateNewAccountBusinessMessage"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/createNewAccountBusinessMessage"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </TextView>

                <CheckBox 
                    android:text="Is business account"
                    android:contentDescription="Is business account? Click for yes"
                    android:id="@+id/isNewBusinessAccountCheck" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </CheckBox>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textPersonName" 
                    android:hint="Business Name"
                    android:id="@+id/newAccountBusinessName" 
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:visibility="invisible">
                    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
                </EditText>

                <EditText 
                    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                    android:hint="Mailing Address" 
                    android:id="@+id/newAccountBusinessAddress"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible">
                </EditText>

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_weight="3" 
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:hint="City" 
                        android:id="@+id/newAccountBusinessCity"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" 
                        android:visibility="invisible">
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_weight="1" 
                        android:maxLength="2"
                        android:hint="St" 
                        android:id="@+id/newAccountBusinessState"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" 
                        android:visibility="invisible">
                    </EditText>

                    <EditText 
                        android:layout_weight="2" 
                        android:maxLength="5"
                        android:hint="Zip" 
                        android:id="@+id/newAccountBusinessZipCode"
                        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" 
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" 
                        android:visibility="invisible">
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView>

        <com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/NextBackScrollView5"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <TextView 
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/CreateNewAccountCompleteMessage"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </TextView>

                <Button 
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:text="Create Account"
                    android:id="@+id/createAccountButton" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="20px"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.appname.UI.Shared.CreateNewAccount.NextBackScrollView>
    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:background="@drawable/new_account_navbar_background"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If and how was it solved?+

Answer (score 0):

We have also run into this, seems like an Android bug.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().keyboardHidden == Configuration.KEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES)
```

problem solved!!

**EDIT:**

I don't believe this was ever actually solved but I am no longer involved in this project.

Comment: Hi, how did this solve your problem? I don't see any Java code in your question. Did you stay with adjustPan or go with adjustResize? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, how does an if-statement solve it? I have the same problem - I have a Button that shoudl "alignBottom" at all times. If I use "adjustPan", then it stays there, but I cannot scroll while the keyboard is up...

Comment: honestly I haven't been a part of this project for almost two years. Thinking about it, I believe this issue was never completely resolved and being that I don't work with this project anymore I have no viable answer to your question...